# Ember.js - Filter messages

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm getting the following JSON response on /messages endpoint:

`{
  "messages": [
    {
      id: 1,
      sender: 2,
      receiver: 1,
      body: "this is a first comment",
      created_at: "2016-09-05 10:00:00",
      updated_at: "2016-09-05 10:00:00",
      user: 2
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      sender: 1,
      receiver: 2,
      body: "this is a second comment",
      created_at: "2016-09-05 11:00:00",
      updated_at: "2016-09-05 11:00:00",
      user: 2
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      sender: 3,
      receiver: 1,
      body: "this is a first comment",
      created_at: "2016-09-05 12:00:00",
      updated_at: "2016-09-05 12:00:00",
      user: 3
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      sender: 1,
      receiver: 3,
      body: "this is a second comment",
      created_at: "2016-09-05 13:00:00",
      updated_at: "2016-09-05 13:00:00",
      user: 3
    },
  ]
}`

These are all the messages the current user has with the other users. The `user` property is the user whom the current user is having the conversation with, whether is receiving from or sending to. I need to filter these messages and get only the last message with each user.

In this example I'll end up with the messages with the id's 1 and 3.

Moving forward I have set up the route `messages/:user_id` and when going to this route you can see all the messages exchanged with that particular user.

If doing the filter I need server side, then when visiting `messages/:user_id` route, all the messages with that user would be loaded in the store. Then when going back to `messages` I get all these messages that were previously loaded in the store.

I've put up an [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/3ded290f746e0ecfce3c0bec4ba9a9e5) to help illustrate this.

I was looking into the [mapBy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_mapBy) and [uniq](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_uniq) methods and toying around with them with no success.

Any directions or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it using an observer on the controller's model:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  messages: Ember.computed('model', function () {
    return this.get('model').sortBy('created_at').reverse().uniqBy('user');
  }),
});
```

You can also chain computed properties together if you have a use for the intermediate states:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  sorting: ['created_at:desc'],
  sortedModel: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sorting'),
  uniqModel: Ember.computed.uniqBy('sortedModel', 'user'),
});
```

You could also do this filtering in the route:

```
// routes/application.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return messages.sortBy('created_at').reverse().uniqBy('user');
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks @maffews, the controller approach works. However I tried this in the route and it doesn't work:  ```model() {
        return this.store.findAll('message').then(function (messages) {
            return messages.sortBy('created_at').reverse().uniqBy('user');
        });
    }model() {
        return this.store.findAll('message').then(function (messages) {
            return messages.sortBy('date').reverse().uniqBy('user');
        });
    }```

Comment: It looks like you've tried two different approaches in the route? What issues/errors do you see?

Comment: Sorry @maffews it was just an error of copy paste. The code I used only is `model() { 
 return this.store.findAll('message').then(function (messages) { 
  return messages.sortBy('created_at').reverse().uniqBy('user'); 
 }); 
}`  There's no error. I get the same problem as in the OP. When visiting a message route more messages are loaded into the store and then when going back to the /messages route I see all these new messages previously loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the recent comment using updated_at field.
changed updated_at time string to timestamp and pick the record with highest timestamp..

```
var data={
  "messages": [
    {
      id: 1,
      sender: 2,
      receiver: 1,
      body: "this is a first comment",
      created_at: "2016-09-05 10:00:00",
      updated_at: "2016-09-05 10:00:00",
      user: 2
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      sender: 1,
      receiver: 2,
      body: "this is a second comment",
      created_at: "2016-09-05 11:00:00",
      updated_at: "2016-09-05 11:00:00",
      user: 2
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      sender: 3,
      receiver: 1,
      body: "this is a first comment",
      created_at: "2016-09-05 12:00:00",
      updated_at: "2016-09-05 12:00:00",
      user: 3
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      sender: 1,
      receiver: 3,
      body: "this is a second comment",
      created_at: "2016-09-05 13:00:00",
      updated_at: "2016-09-05 13:00:00",
      user: 3
    },
  ]
}

var latestMessage=data.messages[0];
data.messages.forEach(function(item){
  if(new Date(item.updated_at).getTime()/1000 > new Date(latestMessage.updated_at).getTime()/1000){
    latestMessage={};
    latestMessage=item;
  }
});
console.log(latestMessage);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: my bad. i tried editing the post later but i was not allowed due to some rating reasons i guess

Comment: could you try again? I'm quite sure you can edit your own answers at any rep. rate.